# returning null when creating a list of Database table

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I'm trying to search in a specific table in database, what I need is to get these values as a list. Here is my code. But the problem is it keeps returning null even when there is data in the table :

```
List<Acc_Info> result = new List<Acc_Info>();
using (DataBase)
{

    IEnumerable<Acc_Info> searchRes = (from f in DataBase.Acc_Infos
                                       where f.UniqueName == s
                                       select f).Distinct();
    result = searchRes.ToList();
}
```

There is a value for "s" and it can see it. I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: This code does not return null (there's no `return` statement) and there's no variable that can be null. Show the entire method containing this code and its call, perhaps there's a `try-catch` block that swallows an exception and returns `null`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, by returning null I mean, that it doesn't return anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

When you say there's a value for "s" you mean for the content fo the variable "s", right? And when you say it returns null you mean it doesn't return any object, right? I ask you this because the code you showed cannot return null.

The first thing I would do is to check the query EF is generating, either by running the code in debug mode or by openning the Database profiler (SQL Server Profiler if you are using SQL Server). Then, you can manually execute that query in the database and figure out what's going on. Your code seems to be OK, it's highly probable that the content of the variable "s" doesn't match with any row in the table.

Comment: Thanks for answering, by returning null I mean, that it doesn't return anything at all, and for the value of "s" yes I mean it's not null, it contains the string, While debugging the values of the list keeps being null. I'm sure of the matching because by another function it searched and let the account to log in, so the data i'm looking for does exist. I also looked up for the data and it does exist in the table.